# Repeat list elements for index times in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I make list [1,2,3] transfer to [1,2,2,3,3,3]. According to the index of the list and make it duplicate for index time.

Comment: `Data.List.replicate` function is your friend...

Comment: You should edit your question to give it a more meaningful title. "About Haskell Language with some question" could apply to any of the 43K+ Haskell questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
f xs = xs `zip` [1..] >>= \(x, n) -> take n (repeat x)
f [1, 5, 8]
-- [1, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you shortly explain how it works? I'm a new learner for the Haskell language.

Comment: `take n (repeat x)` is just `replicate n x`.

Comment: Flip the arguments, and you can write this as `zip [1..] xs >>= uncurry replicate`.

Comment: Or `f = concat . zipWith replicate [1..]`.

Comment: @chepner Didn't want to confuse a newcomer with point free style.

Comment: `f xs = concat (zipWith replicate [1..] xs)`; using the right higher-order functions is probably the important point.

Comment: or `f = zip [1..] >=> uncurry replicate`